# Image auto scrolling in android

Tags: android, image, animation, scroll

I want to create an image auto scrolling for an outer-space type of game. To make it more exact, I want to load 2 background image that uses a single image occupying the whole screen and auto-scroll it alternatively to create an animation that the background image is moving. Don't get confused with auto scrolling and and shifting to another image automatically. I really meant auto scrolling like moving background using 1 image.

I did some research but what I saw are segments of java codes that made me confused. If possible can anyone provide me an example? From loading the image from xml (should I use an imageview with this? or just set the background image of the layout?) and how I should process it in java code to make an image autoscrolling.

Any ideas guys? Thanks! Sorry for asking too much.